# Differences between Bitcoin and Monero mining pool software

Tags: mining-pools

How different are Monero mining pool software from the equivalent for Bitcoin?

In particular, would forking p2pool to adapt it to Monero be more efficient than starting from scratch or is there too much specificities due to Monero not being derived from Bitcoin codebase?